# Strange behavior of returned value when using apply() to subset a matrix

Tags: r, subset, apply

I feel like this must be something obvious but I have spent all day trying to puzzle it out and searching for answers so I'm posting it here hoping someone has some input.

The short version is that using apply() to subset a data frame by values in another data frame and return a mean, the function returns NA for the first 9 iterations if the number of input rows is greater than 9. If the number of input rows are less than 9 it returns that data just fine. It isn't obvious to me what I've done to cause that.

I have two data frames. The first is data taken sequentially from numerous samples. factor levels of the "ID" column represent the sample. Within each factor the "Length" column corresponds to where the measurement was taken in a line across the sample. There are two data columns for two different measurements. Below is a simplified, repeatable, representation of what this looks like:

```
set.seed(10)
ID=factor(sort(rep(paste(letters[1:10]), times=10)))
Length=seq(1:10) + runif(10, 0, 0.9)
Values_1=c(1:20)
Values_2=c(21:40)
test_data=cbind.data.frame(ID, Length, Values_1, Values_2)
```

Next I have a matrix of cutoff values that I want to use to subset the "Length" column in "test_data". Each row shows which sample I want to subset, and the start and end points of the subset.

```
ID2=sort(rep(paste(letters[1:10]), times=2)) 
Start=c(1, 5, 1, 5)
Stop=c(5, 10, 7, 10)
Row=c(1:20)
cutoffs=cbind.data.frame(ID2, Start, Stop, Row)
colnames(cutoffs)=c("ID", "Start", "Stop", "Row")
#I'm recycling the cutoffs here. In reality the cutoffs are all pretty different
```

If I subset the data manually it works for any row I pick,

```
r=9
subset1=test_data$Values_1[test_data[,1] == cutoffs[r,1] &
                           test_data[,2] >= cutoffs[r,2] &
                           test_data[,2] <= cutoffs[r,3] &
                           !is.na(test_data[,3])]
#[1] 1 2 3 4
mean(subset1)
#There are no NA's in this test data, but the !is.na is there to catch NA's that exist in the real data
```

but when I build an apply function to subset all the data things get weird and I don't know why. If I run the function it only returns the values for cutoffs[10:20,] and the first 9 samples are given NA's. But running any subset of cutoffs between rows 1 and 9 returns the correct values.

```
apply(cutoffs, 1, function(x){
  subset_1=test_data$Values_1[test_data[,1] == cutoffs[x[4],1] &
                              test_data[,2] >= cutoffs[x[4],2] &
                              test_data[,2] <= cutoffs[x[4],3] &
                              !is.na(test_data[,3])]
  subset_2=test_data$Values_2[test_data[,1] == cutoffs[x[4],1] &
                              test_data[,2] >= cutoffs[x[4],2] &
                              test_data[,2] <= cutoffs[x[4],3] &
                              !is.na(test_data[,4])]
  Mean_1=mean(subset_1)
  Mean_2=mean(subset_2)
  c(Mean_1, Mean_2)
})

    #     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
    #[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA     7  13.5    17   2.5     7  13.5    17   2.5     7  13.5    17
    #[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    27  33.5    37  22.5    27  33.5    37  22.5    27  33.5    37

#Running the same function, but subsetting below 9 rows it returns the correct values
#apply(cutoffs[1:9,], 1, function(x){...
#        1  2    3  4    5  6    7  8    9
#[1,]  2.5  7 13.5 17  2.5  7 13.5 17  2.5
#[2,] 22.5 27 33.5 37 22.5 27 33.5 37 22.5
```

I know there must be some good reason for this but I can't figure out what it is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If there is a more elegant way to do this let me know. The actual dataset is a much larger, the equivalent of "cutoffs" is around 3K rows and "test_data" is 250K rows. This function takes a long time to run so I'm assuming there are much better ways to do this.

Comment: Can you show the expected output?  Is it just a subset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, **don't use `apply` on a data frame.** It will convert the df into a matrix, which means that all the columns will be coerced into a single type. In particular, if any of the columns are character or factor, the resulting matrix will also be character.

But that isn't the problem. Let's look at the first code chunk you've presented:

```
subset1 <- test_data$Values_1[test_data[,1] == cutoffs[r,1] &
                              test_data[,2] >= cutoffs[r,2] &
                              test_data[,2] <= cutoffs[r,3] &
                              !is.na(test_data[,3])]
```

And the second code chunk:

```
subset_1 <- test_data$Values_1[test_data[,1] == cutoffs[x[4],1] &
                               test_data[,2] >= cutoffs[x[4],2] &
                               test_data[,2] <= cutoffs[x[4],3] &
                               !is.na(test_data[,3])]
subset_2 <- test_data$Values_2[test_data[,1] == cutoffs[x[4],1] &
                               test_data[,2] >= cutoffs[x[4],2] &
                               test_data[,2] <= cutoffs[x[4],3] &
                               !is.na(test_data[,4])]
```

These aren't the same (what is the significance of the 4th element of `x`?). Assuming the first code chunk is what you want, then applying it across all rows would look like this.

```
sapply(seq_len(nrow(cutoffs)), function(r) {
    vals1 <- test_data$Values_1[test_data[,1] == cutoffs[r,1] &
                                test_data[,2] >= cutoffs[r,2] &
                                test_data[,2] <= cutoffs[r,3] &
                                !is.na(test_data[,3])]
    vals2 <- test_data$Values_2[test_data[,1] == cutoffs[r,1] &
                                test_data[,2] >= cutoffs[r,2] &
                                test_data[,2] <= cutoffs[r,3] &
                                !is.na(test_data[,3])]
    c(mean(vals1), mean(vals2))
})

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
#[1,]  2.5    7 13.5   17  2.5    7 13.5   17  2.5     7  13.5    17   2.5     7  13.5    17   2.5     7  13.5    17
#[2,] 22.5   27 33.5   37 22.5   27 33.5   37 22.5    27  33.5    37  22.5    27  33.5    37  22.5    27  33.5    37
```

Comment: Just so I'm clear on why this problem happened. 'apply(cutoffs, 1, function(x){x})' returns the entire row for each iteration. That's why I was using 'x[4]', because the 4th column is simply the row number in sequence. Is it something internal to apply() that causes the NAs to come up after 10 iterations, something about calling 'x[4]', or something else?

Comment: If I understand you correctly since the first column of `cutoffs's`is character, then all the columns become character using apply(). So, is the behavior something to do with how R works with x[4] once it's been turned to character? If so, what is it? I would think it would fail for all of the iterations in that case.